# Use purrr's map() function on get() within function, results in object not found

Tags: r, scope, environment, purrr

When using the following code:

```
get_objects <- function() {
    x1 <- 123
    x2 <- 23535

    x_objects <- ls(pattern = 'x')
    print(x_objects)
    x_objects_list <- purrr::map(x_objects, get)

    return(x_objects_list)

} 

f <- get_objects()
```

I get the following error:

> Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'x1' not found

I suspect it has something to do with the scoping or environment, as when the object is globally defined, instead of in the function, I can use the code by evaluating

```
x_objects_list <- purrr::map(x_objects, get)
```

directly in the console. The reason is that I want a list of dataframes with a certain name so I can iteratively perform actions on them.

Comment: Run it with out using a function, it woks fine

Comment: You should be using `mget()`

Comment: Could you specify why @andrew?

Comment: Just look at `?mget`.  `purrr::map(x_objects, get)` is equivalent to `mget(x_objects)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but as you do not share you bigger scope, this should solve you current issue:

```
get_objects <- function() {
    x1 <- 123
    x2 <- 23535

    x_objects <- ls(pattern = 'x')
    x_objects_list <- purrr::map(x_objects, get, envir = sys.frame(sys.parent(0)))

    return(x_objects_list)

} 

f <- get_objects()
```